# MS Sql Server table based user authorization

Tags: sql-server-2005, authorization

I want to restrict some MS Sql Server users. For example, one user should just be able to see 2 columns of "Customers" table and none other. And this user shouldn't be able to create any manipulation queries. But one user should be able to do everything on all tables and all columns. How do i do that?

BR,

Çağın

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find a way like this :

- Click securables tab from user name on database's security.
- Click search button and choose object type. (I need just tables)
- Click Browse and choose table(s) and click OK
- Choose Explicit and click Column Permissions
- Choose Columns and click OK

it is working for my situation.

Answer (score 3):

Create a view that only selects the two columns in question. Then remove the `select`, `update` and `insert` grants from the original table, and only grant the user `select` on the new view.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [datareaders role](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/1479511/SQL-Permissions-DataReader--DataWriter-Roles.htm) to restrict write access, and use a view to hide columns. Remove the the select right on the table to prevent a query directly on it.